# Why is the directory Windows/Temp used instead of the Local user Temp when using %TEMP%

Tags: windows, environment-variables

After installing my system in a new season of work, you must create a mechanism to actualize the same. This mechanism of this command line:

```
schtasks /CREATE /SC onstart /DELAY 0015: 00 /TN "AppName Update" /TR "cmd /c bitsadmin /transfer My Download/Download/ PRIORITY HIGH ftp.link.com/MyApp.exe %TEMP%\MyApp.exe & %Temp%\MyApp.exe " /ru SYSTEM
```

Here the installer should create a scheduled task for the whole time the operational system starts downloading and running the package installer.

But after the OS reboot and run the task, the download and made but not saved in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\` but in `C:\Windows\Temp` and therefore reflected in the rest of the installation.

I have done a reading on the msdn documentation schtasks.exe in, but not became very clear to me. but I believe that the problem of this parameter here: `/ru SYSTEM`.

If someone power of any explanation of why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your task runs as system, a special account that does not have its own user profile and its %temp% variable, points to c:\windows\temp

You should use a different user to run the task, system is too powerful.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Any tips on which profile to use without need to ask User and password it?

Comment: The problem still remains. Someone to help?